# TypeError: tizen.filesystem.openFile is not a function

Tags: filesystems, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

When I run as my web app in Tizen Web Simulator Application(Samsung TV 5.5), I get the exception as followed:

> TypeError: tizen.filesystem.openFile is not a function

My source is from [here](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/latest/device_api/mobile/tizen/filesystem.html#FileSystemManager)

Here is the source:

```
function read_file() {

    alert('read_file()');
    try {
        var fileHandleRead = tizen.filesystem.openFile("documents/file", "r");
        //console.log("File opened for reading");
        alert("File opened for reading");
        var fileContent = fileHandleRead.readString();
        //console.log("File content: " + fileContent);
        alert("File content: " + fileContent);
        fileHandleRead.close(); 
    } catch (e) {
        alert("read_file exception: " + e);
    }
 }
```

appreciated

Answer (score 2):

[Tizen Web Simulator](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/tv-simulator.html) is:

> suitable for UI development or testing application features which use basic Samsung Product or Tizen APIs.

and

> Unlike Samsung TVs and the Samsung TV Emulator, the **simulator does not actually run the Samsung TV platform**. The simulator is a WebKit-based application that simulates Samsung TV APIs using a JavaScript backend. As a result, the simulator does not support any features that have strict dependencies on TV hardware or core Tizen modules.

According to that some APIs may not work on Simulator.
I suggest you to check features on TV **[Emulator](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/tv-emulator.html)** (at least 5.0 to use *tizen.filesystem.openFile()*).